# Is it correct to use "pointing out" in this context?

Tags: grammaticality, phrasal-verbs, syntactic-analysis

I am writing in this context

> I am so excited about XXXX.
>
> Thanks a lot for **pointing it out** to me.
>
> You are great

Is  **point out** the correct expression to use?

Note: the one I am sending the email to, is the one who told me about this thing that seems that I like a lot.

Thanks

Comment: ***point something out*** *phrasal verb of point* say something to make someone aware of a fact or circumstance. "she pointed out that his van had been in the parking lot all day" synonyms: *identify, show, designate, draw attention to, indicate, specify, detail, mention* -- https://www.google.com/#q=point+out+synonym Why the doubt then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, *point something out* means to direct one's attention to something with your hand or finger or to say something about someone/something in order to make someone aware of something. I don't know what the person has told you, but looking at it from what we have, it looks like you want to say something along the lines of *sharing with me.*

> Thank you for sharing this/that with me.

If it was a mistake or something similar that he/she pointed out, then your usage would be fine.

Comment: Exactly he did that. He direct me to study this thing and I like it. So, after you knew what he did, would it be better to use share or point?

Comment: '[T]o say something about someone/something in order to make someone aware of something' licenses OP's usage completely.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Got you :)